# Adding a new Instance in weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

How can I add a new Instance to an existing Instances object that I created ?

Here is an example:

```
ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>(2);
ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();
classVal.add("A");
classVal.add("B");
atts.add(new Attribute("content",(ArrayList<String>)null));
atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@",classVal));

Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstances",atts,0);
```

I want to add a new instance to dataRaw. As far as I know I have to use dataRaw.add(Instance i) .... How can I create an instance object if the Instance class is an interface ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pass an implementation of `Instance`, which you can see [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instance.html) under __All Known Implementing Classes__.

Comment: PS you won't be able to add anything, since you passed `0` to the `capacity` argument in the constructor.

Comment: I followed this guide here (http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) and as far as I understood this is the initial capacity. could you please give me an example how to add a new instance to the object that I created ? Thanks ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let start with some highlights.

- weka stores every instance value as double[]. Therefore you create double[] instanceValue1 and add values to this array.
- Even strings are stored in this double[]. You add your string values with following code:

> instanceValue1[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("This is a string!");

- Instance is interface, and it is implemented by two classes, { SparseInstance , DenseInstance}. We add our value array to dataset using  following code :

> dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

Here is the complete running example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>(2);
        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();
        classVal.add("A");
        classVal.add("B");
        atts.add(new Attribute("content",(ArrayList<String>)null));
        atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@",classVal));

        Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstances",atts,0);
        System.out.println("Before adding any instance");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println(dataRaw);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        double[] instanceValue1 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue1[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("This is a string!");
        instanceValue1[1] = 0;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

        System.out.println("After adding a instance");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println(dataRaw);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        double[] instanceValue2 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue2[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("This is second string!");
        instanceValue2[1] = 1;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue2));

        System.out.println("After adding second instance");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println(dataRaw);
        System.out.println("--------------------------");


    }

}
```

Its output is following:

```
Before adding any instance
--------------------------
@relation TestInstances

@attribute content string
@attribute @@class@@ {A,B}

@data

--------------------------
After adding a instance
--------------------------
@relation TestInstances

@attribute content string
@attribute @@class@@ {A,B}

@data
'This is a string!',A
--------------------------
After adding second instance
--------------------------
@relation TestInstances

@attribute content string
@attribute @@class@@ {A,B}

@data
'This is a string!',A
'This is second string!',B
--------------------------
```

Comment: May i know which api did you use?

Comment: Weka and normal java collections api.

Comment: Hi @AtillaOzgur I got -1 for "dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("This is second string!");" part in my code when I try to assign to the double[] var

Can you give a hint please......