# Unable to create instances with string and numeric attributes WEKA

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, weka

I have written a filter in weka for my research. When I apply my filter to my dataset (let's call this from now on *oldData*) it is applied on one of the attributes specified with Range. In the instances the attribute is replaced with values of type Double and the header is adapted accordingly.

However, now I wish to copy the attributes from *oldData* on which the filter was not applied (so the attributes not in the Range). This attribute is a String attribute. With the code I have written I get in the instances `*WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*` while it has to be the original value as in *oldData*.

Here is a simple example (how it looks in *oldData*):

```
@attribute attr_text string
@attribute attr_tags string

@data
'some text','some tags'
'some text','some tags'
```

I apply my filter to the first attribute (i.e., `attr_text`) and get this:

```
@attribute attr_tags string
@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 numeric
...

@data
'some text',0.0136,0.0024, ...
'some text',0.0041,0.0387, ...
```

So this is what I wish to accomplish. However the first attribute of each instance is `*WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*`.

Here is the code where I perform all this:

```
// STEP 4 - add instances
DenseInstance denseInstance = null;
for (int i = 0; i < inst.numInstances(); i++) {
   double[] newValues = new double[getK() + 1];
   for (int t = 1; t <= getK(); t++) {
      newValues[t] = theta[i][t-1];
   }
   denseInstance = new DenseInstance(1.0, newValues);
   // Adding the following two lines solved my problem!
   denseInstance.setDataset(oldData);
   dennseInstance.setValue(0, inst.Instance(i).stringValue(1); // 1 is the attribute index
   //-----
   push(denseInstance);
}
```

As you will see, the array newValues starts inserting at idx 1 since I wish to insert the string at index 0.

**Edit1**
So the question is, how can I copy the `attr_tags` attribute in each instance from *oldData* to the new instance?

**Edit2**
I have based myself on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118132/adding-a-new-instance-in-weka) post but it seems not to work, it prints the DUMMY text.

**Edit3**
I solved the issue myself. I added two lines of code in my snippet which solved the problem.

Comment: Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?